# Testing for Null and not Null in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What is the best / cleanest / advisable way to test if a value is Null in Mathematica ? And Not Null?

For example:

```
 a = Null
 b = 0;
 f[n_] := If[n == Null, 1, 2]
 f[a]
 f[b]
```

has the result:

```
 1
 If[0 == Null, 1, 2]
```

Where I would have expected that 2 for f[b].

Comment: Use SameQ (===) instead of Equal in your predicate test.

Comment: That does it! Equal Same. I have to check why there is a difference.

Comment: I cover this topic here: http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node24.html

Comment: your book looks nice in this website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As pointed out by Daniel (and explained in Leonid's book) `Null == 0` does not evaluate to either `True` or `False`, so the `If` statement (as written) also does not evaluate.
`Null` is a special `Symbol` that does not display in output, but in all other ways acts like a normal, everyday symbol.

```
In[1]:= Head[Null]
Out[1]= Symbol
```

For some undefined symbol `x`, you don't want `x == 0` to return `False`, since `x` could be zero later on. This is why `Null == 0` also doesn't evaluate.

There are two possible fixes for this:

**1)** Force the test to evaluate using `TrueQ` or `SameQ`.
For the `n == Null` test, the following will equivalent, but when testing numerical objects they will not. (This is because `Equal` uses an approximate test for numerical equivalence.)

```
f[n_] := If[TrueQ[n == Null], 1, 2]   (* TrueQ *)
f[n_] := If[n === Null, 1, 2]         (* SameQ *)
```

Using the above, the conditional statement works as you wanted:

```
In[3]:= {f[Null], f[0]}
Out[3]= {1, 2}
```

**2)** Use the optional 4th argument of `If` that is returned if the test remains unevaluated (i.e. if it is neither `True` nor `False`)

```
g[n_] := If[n == Null, 1, 2, 3]
```

Then

```
In[5]:= {g[Null], g[0]}
Out[5]= {1, 3}
```

Comment: Behaviour seems to have changed since at most Version 12.2: Now, Null == Null returns True.

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to have two DownValues, one for the special condition Null, and your normal definition.  This has the advantage that you don't need to worry about Null in the second one.

```
f[Null] := 1

f[x_] := x^2 (* no weird Null^2 coming out of here! *)
```