# Matching head different from some pattern

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to match expression who's head differs from f.

This works

```
[In]  !MatchQ[t[3], x_ /; Head[x] == f]
[Out] True
```

But not this

```
 [In]  MatchQ[t[3], x_ /; Head[x] != f]
 [Out] False
```

Why does the second solution not work? How can I make it work?

Comment: Related SO questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286736/difference-between-and-in-mathematica, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750623/using-position-correctly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510289/testing-for-null-and-not-null-in-mathematica

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why this does not work:  you must use  `=!=`  ([`UnsameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnsameQ.html)), rather than `!=` ([`Unequal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unequal.html)) for structural comparisons:

```
In[18]:= MatchQ[t[3],x_/;Head[x]=!=f]
Out[18]= True
```

The reason can be seen by evaluating this:

```
In[22]:= Head[t[3]]!=f
Out[22]= t!=f
```

The operators `==` (`Equal`) and `!=` (`Unequal`) do evaluate to themselves, when the fact of equality (or inequality) of the two sides can not be established. This makes sense in a symbolic environment. I considered this topic in more detail [here](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node24.html), where also `SameQ` and `UnsameQ` are discussed.

There are also more elegant ways to express the same pattern, which will be more efficient as well, such as this:

```
MatchQ[t[3],Except[_f]]
```